# Distance of a plane

Tags: plane-geometry

I have posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52894975/what-is-the-distance-of-the-plane-in-accord-framework?noredirect=1#comment92702911_52894975) in Stack Overflow programming forum. Someone there feels it might be more suited to Mathematics.

I have to warn you I am rusty in math and was terrible in Algebra.

Using [Accord Framework plane class](http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/T_Accord_Math_Plane.htm). The help on [this page](http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/M_Accord_Math_Plane__ctor_3.htm) specifies a constructor that creates a plane a certain distance from the origin. I am getting numbers that do not make sense. If I create a plane using the vector 5,5,5 at a distance of 1 then I would expect the plane to be 1 away from the origin:

```
        Plane p = new Plane(new Vector3(5,5,5),1);
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", p.DistanceToPoint(new Point3(0,0,0)));
```

Instead I get the value of 0.115470053837925.

The only way I get a distance that makes sense is to create a plane using one of the three constructors below:

```
        Plane p = new Plane(new Vector3(0,0,1),1);
        Plane p = new Plane(new Vector3(0,1,0),1);
        Plane p = new Plane(new Vector3(1,0,0),1);
```

When using any of these constructors I get a distance of 1 from the origin.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Notice that $0.115470053837925=1/\sqrt{5^2+5^2+5^2}$, which is not by coincidence.

Comment: doesn't look right. get the properties $p.A, p.B, p.C$ to check the equation of the plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either the API or the documentation are wrong.

Regardless the other arguments, *Offset* is deemed to specify the distance from the plane to the origin, and *DistanceToPoint* should return the same value.

---

I strongly suspect that *Offset* is in reality the parameter *d* of the equation, and the normal vector is never normalized. Indeed,

$$5x+5y+5z+1=0$$

defines a plane at distance $\dfrac1{5\sqrt3}$ of the origin.

---

Try with

```
Vector3 v= new Vector3(5, 5, 5); v.Normalize();
Plane p = new Plane(v, 1);
```

Comment: That is it the solution. Normalizing the vector achieves the correct distance.

Answer (score 0):

The generic plane equation can be written as

$$
(p-p_0)\cdot \vec n = 0
$$

with $p = (x,y,z)$ In our case

$$
\vec n = (5,5,5) =5\sqrt 3\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt 3}(1,1,1)\right)
$$

where $\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}(1,1,1) = \frac{\vec n}{||\vec n||}$ Choosing a plane at a distance $d$ from the origin means that

$$
p_0 = d\frac{\vec n}{||\vec n||} = 1\times \frac{1}{\sqrt 3}(1,1,1)
$$

so the sought plane is

$$
(p - 1\times \frac{1}{\sqrt 3}(1,1,1))\cdot (5,5,5) = 0
$$

or

$$
5x+5y+5z-5\sqrt 3 = 0
$$

0r

$$
x+y+z-\sqrt 3 = 0
$$

Comment: It seems that either software or documentation is wrong as it definitely produces wrong distance to the origin.